# Creating a dynamic graph and pie chart like goo.gl statistics

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am fairly new to HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery and was wondering how to create goo.gl statistics like dynamic graph and pie chart using them.

[image]
Any help from you guys will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
EG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has free [chart tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) that you can use and of course their documentation is excellent. There is also the [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) library that you can download and use.

Comment: It's for my client and I might not be allowed to use Google Charts. I'll try using RGraph. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest looking at Bonsai.js It's a API for rendering SVG (perhaps SVG's may work better for your client).

http://bonsaijs.org/

And a demo relating to your question:

http://demos.bonsaijs.org/demos/pie/index.html